# What is the best practice to mention "conference presentations" in CV

Tags: cv

I'm going to apply to a graduate program which asks me to declare my conference presentations in my CV.

I have 9 proceeding papers, 8 of which are presented by myself, and I have another section in my CV, called "publications", in which the papers are meticulously cited.

Now, I am thinking of the best approach to mentioning my presentations, which can be some references to the publications section of the CV without rewriting complete information of each paper (such as its title, venue, etc.) as the following:

**Publications:**

9 - Me, et al., "the title 9", venue, pp., 20XX,

8 - Me, et al., "the title 8", venue, pp., 20XX,

.
.
.

1 - Me, et al., "the title 1", venue, pp., 20XX,

**Presentations:**

Sept. 20XX - Presenter of the 9th Proceeding Paper, venue 9,

Sept. 20XX - Presenter of the 7th Proceeding Paper, venue 7,

.
.
.

Sept. 20XX - Presenter of the 1st Proceeding Paper, venue 1,

---

I'm wondering whether this kind of referring is the etiquette and is kinda professional or I better rewrite information of all papers again.

Comment: Have you considered looking at what people who are attending the program do on their CVs?

Comment: My experience is that paper presentations are not reported separately on a CV. More distinguished presentations, like invited talks or keynotes, would be listed under a section called something like "Invited Talks"

Comment: @Dawn: Unfortunately, I couldn't find any sort of related CVs.

Comment: @David: As I explicitly stated: I've been asked to do so.

Comment: What field is this (I guess CS?)? Do you have any publications that are not proceeding papers or any presentations without a proceeding paper?

Comment: @DSVA The field is almost similar to CS, it's EE, and I have 4 Journal papers, too.

Comment: @DSVA and I don't have any presentations without a proceeding paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to avoid having the same information twice or referring to another section in your CV, that makes it complicated to read.

What I would do, but this is of course something subjective, is having one section for "journal papers", one for "conference papers", depending on your field they might be worth as much as journal papers, if that's the case then just one section, for example "peer reviewed articles". And one for "oral contributions including conference papers". I guess there's a better name for that but I would put the presentation and the paper into one entry:

> How to write a CV
>
> **DSVA**, Some else, another person
>
> presented at some conference, 01.01.1971, the internet
>
> published in: Me, et al., "the title 1", venue, pp., 20XX,

If the authors are the same I would leave out the second line.

The alternative would be just adding the information about the talk to the paper section by adding:

> Presented by DSVA in an oral communication at some conference, date

Since the conference paper and the presentation seem to be very tied together this would make a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks. I think "the alternative" is so compact and effective.